# How to sync existing files in file system to Silverstripe Document Management System?

Tags: silverstripe

I've just added the [Silverstripe Document Management System](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-dms) to a Silverstripe 3.1 project.

I would have thought that there would be a way syncing the DMS with existing files in the file system. This exists in the basic File Management section, which is separate from the DMS module.

In this case we have 116 PDF documents in the "/dms-assets/" directory which need to be imported into the DMS.

The only other documentation I can find about the DMS is [this blog post](http://www.silverstripe.org/document-management-system-module/).

I'm probably missing something really obvious, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is additional documentation for the DMS module on github:

https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-dms

However, I'm afraid that the specific "sync" feature you are asking about does not exist.

What I would do to bulk-import 116 PDFs is to drag the files onto a page's "add documents" area, and re-upload all the files. This kind of uploading creates the necessary database records for all the uploaded documents and associates them with the relevant page. Just doing a sync of the file system doesn't make sense in the context of the DMS, because all documents are associated with one or more page. The DMS automatically deletes a document when you remove it from all it's associated pages. So, a filesystem sync of documents would just result in a bunch of orphaned documents.

I hope that helps.